# Convert Days, Hours, Minutes to Seconds (Dd HH:MM:SS) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can i convert cell in excel to seconds

Example:

```
2d 07:51:00
```

Expected Output:

```
201060
```

Comment: by my math it should be `201060` seconds.  Is there a reason I am wrong?

Comment: @ScottCraner mistype but u solved it thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one has TEXTSPLIT:

```
=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),"d",""))*86400
```

[image]

Else:

```
=(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),"d","")+MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))*86400
```

[image]